# Haskell split tuple array where first elements are the same

Tags: list, haskell, split, tuples

I have a list in Haskell of a form similar to

```
[([], "str1"), ([], "str2"), ([1], "ser1")]
```

and I want to split this into separate lists of 2-tuples, where the first elements of each tuple are the same, like so

```
[([], "str1"), ([], "str2")]
[([1], "ser1")]
```

I''ve been eyeing `Data.List.Split`'s `splitWhen` function, but I've been having trouble getting `ghc` to accept a predicate for it, since I gather it really wasn't meant to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can just use `groupBy`:

```
> import Data.List
> import Data.Function

> let xs = [([], "str1"), ([], "str2"), ([1], "ser1")]

> groupBy ((==) `on` fst) xs

[[([],"str1"),([],"str2")], [([1],"ser1")]]
```

Comment: Well, I really should have caught that. Thanks!

Comment: `groupBy (\x y -> fst x == fst y)` can be replaced by ``groupBy ((==) `on` fst)`` after importing [`Data.Function.on`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on).

Comment: Note that the predicate can be written `(==) \`on\` fst` with Data.Function. on.

Comment: Thanks; I had a feeling it could probably be written more concisely - will update my answer ;-)